# Expectation of uniform ratio distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two independent uniformly distributed random variables $X, Y \sim Uni[0,1]$.

> I want to calculate $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)$.

My work:

Because of independence
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{X}{Y} \leq a \right) = 
\begin{cases}
\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_{ax}^1 1\cdot 1\,dx\,dy = \ldots = 1 - \frac{a}{2}, \qquad a \in [0, 1] \\
 \int\limits_0^{1/a}\int\limits_{ax}^1 1\cdot 1\,dx\,dy= \ldots = \frac{1}{2a^2}, \qquad a > 1 
\end{cases}$$

Then i can differentiate the expression with regards to $a$ and get
$$f_{ratio} = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}, \qquad a\in[0,1]\\ \frac{1}{2a^2}, \qquad a > 1\end{cases}$$

And expectation could then be calculated
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right) = \int\limits_0^1\frac{a}{2}\,da + \int\limits_1^{\infty}\frac{a}{2a^2}\,da = \frac{1}{4} + \log (2a) \Big|_1^{\infty} = \infty$$

What I don't understand $\frac{Y}{X} = \frac{1}{\frac{X}{Y}}$, but they both distributed identically.

> Should not then $\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{Y}{X}\right) = 0$ ?

Comment: Why do you think it should be $0$, are you thinking that $\Bbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{X}{Y}}\right]$ should equal $\frac{1}{\Bbb{E}\left[\frac{X}{Y}\right]}$? Remember, $\Bbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{Z}\right]$ does not generally equal $\frac{1}{\Bbb{E}[Z]}$.

Comment: How can a strictly positive random variable have zero mean? You probably meant $E\frac X Y =1$ but that is also  a bad guess by above comment.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy This is the conclusion I wanted to get to. So probably I missing something.

Comment: Your result is correct: you have calculated correctly the PDF, but the first moment diverges.

Comment: how about using transformation theorem to find distriution of X/Y and then finding its expectation.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze is correct.  And if you use certain functions in *Mathematica*, you get the incorrect answer of $0$ for the mean:  `Mean[TransformedDistribution[
  x/y, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
   y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]}]]`.

Comment: @ dEmigOd You can show that the mean of the $a$-th power of $\frac{X}{Y}$ with $0\lt a \lt 1$ is finite and given by $\frac{1}{1-a^2}$. This also shows the divergence if $a \to 1$.

Comment: @ JimB Mathematica calculates the TranformedDistribution correctly but it struggles when it comes to the mean because it boils down to a divergent integral. Of course, Mathematica should give a warning instead of a wrong result ($0$).

Comment: $\mathbb E\left[\frac XY\right] = \infty$